Has the Journal of Fluid Mechanics really published more than 800 volumes?
I currently want to cite this article from the Journal of Fluid Mechanics, but what strikes me is the high volume number (879). To what I have found:

the volume number refers to the number of years a journal has been in publication

So could it be that long?

The statement you've quoted is not true for all journals.  Perhaps you should provide a citation for the statement.

Granted I spend my time in the humanities, not natural sciences, but I don’t know of a single journal where volume number = number of years the journal has been published. Even for the ones where the aim is to publish exactly one volume every year, something inevitably goes wrong at some point to break the equivalence.

In addition, even where there are yearly volumes, they often run from a random month (feb-feb), so finding the volume from the year is further complicated. Then there are journals where the month epoch changes, particularly around things like 1940 (for journals published in europe)...

Check out Proceedings of SPIE. They're on volume 13211 as of now; they publish one volume per conference, and for the SPIE, that works out to be more than 1 a day.

In the same vein as the comment of Nij (and to add some data) in this case it is extremely easy to ascertain the truth of the matter, for example by using Mathscinet: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/serials/issues?groupId=2338 The linked search returns 1054 issues with the latest one in volume 988. (The listing there has some gaps, but checking the journal website shows that there are indeed 988 volumes to date.) The current output appears to be 24 volumes per year.

From the website it looks like they publish a "volume" every two weeks which would mean that the journal is somewhat between 30 and 40 years old.
I do not know if there is a universally agreed upon standard for what a "volume" should mean. The purpose of a citation is to identify the source exactly and uniquely so just cite it as the journal indicates. Everything is fine with the journal.

Spend enough time here and  you learn there's no universally agreed-upon standard for anything.

The Journal of Alloys and Compounds is now up to volume 1002. Some use the same volume number for multiple issues in one year. some use the same volume number for multiple issues in half a year. Some use the volume number for each issue. Publishers are weird...

@JonCuster And the current volume number of Journal of High Energy Physics is 2024 because they just use the year to label volumes.

@Anyon - wait, that actually makes sense! How could that be???

I think the "standard" for a volume is "a reasonable number of pages to fit in a single physical bound volume".  That's the original purpose of volume numbering, after all, even if it has mostly become irrelevant with online publishing. So it makes sense that a big journal which puts out a lot of pages per year would need several volumes per year.

@JonCuster It only makes sense until you (inevitably) get snowballing delays, in which case you either end up with the 2021 issue appearing in 2023, the 2022 issue in 2025, etc.; or with some very unorthodox volume numbering (2019, 2020, 2022, 2025, etc.).

@JanusBahsJacquet I'm not sure what your implying. If your research isn't ready for publication in 2021, you publish it in the 2022 volume. There's presumably going to be other contributions that make up the 2021 volume. So there wouldn't be missing years.

@ChellCPlus No, there absolutely are missing years. I’m not talking about authors not making the submission cutoff, but the process of editing, typesetting, proofreading, etc., after articles have been accepted. Lots of smaller journals, at least in the humanities, are handled entirely by people who do so as part of their full-time university jobs and have more urgent responsibilities to grapple with (teaching, their own research, admin), and journal editing often takes a back seat to more urgent teaching, researching and admin tasks.

@JanusBahsJacquet Ah I see what you mean, I suppose journals like JHEP just have more resources so they can get away with it. Makes sense.

@AzorAhai-him- Mandatory xkcd.

Journal volume numbering practices are not universal. While a significant number may follow an annual volume model consisting of of some number of issues, that is far from accepted standard. There are several common practices.

volumes begin with number 1 and contain some number of issues - often monthly or weekly.
volumes begin with the year of publication and correspond to the year of publication, and consist of issues as above
the volume numbers themselves are assigned for each issue, which are published monthly or weekly, with no subissues (this is likely the situation you are describing)

There are other possibilities, of course, but these are the most common.
If you consider that a monthly "volume" for a journal would rack up about around 600 volumes between over 50 years, and weekly "volumes" would rack up some 2,600 volumes over the same period, the number you cite is not unreasonable. Just look to the journal's publication history and dates, as well as their "About the journal" page to see their typical publication schedule. As someone above mentioned, this journal publishes every two weeks currently, so assuming that same pace for their entire publication history, they would have published more than 1,768 volumes since they launched in 1956 ((2000-1956)*26 issues per year).
